# How do I populate one text-list upon the selection of another text-list?

Tags: rebol

I have some JSON data that I'm converting to Rebol blocks using http://reb4.me/r/altjson that looks something like this:

```
jobs_data: make object! [
    sections: [
        make object! [
            id: "1"
            title: "Section Title 1"
            jobs: [
                make object! [
                    id: "101"
                    title: "Job Title 1"
                    description: {Job description one.}
                ]
            ]
        ]
        make object! [
            id: "2"
            title: "Section Title 2"
            jobs: [
                make object! [
                    id: "201"
                    title: "Job Title 2"
                    description: {Job description two.}
                ]
                make object! [
                    id: "202"
                    title: "Job Title 3"
                    description: {Job description three.}
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

I'm populating one text-list with all the section titles by doing:

```
text-list data (map-each section jobs_data/sections [section/title])
```

I also have a blank text-list below that one.  I want to populate that second text list with the job titles of the selected section.  How do I go about doing that?  I've tried something like this:

```
REBOL []

do http://reb4.me/r/altjson

jobs_data: load-json %./jobs.json

view layout [
    sections: text-list data (map-each section jobs_data/sections [section/title]) [
        ; How do I get the jobs of the given section?
    ]

    jobs: text-list
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:

```
REBOL []

do http://reb4.me/r/altjson

jobs_data: load-json %./jobs.json
currently_selected: copy []

view layout [
    sections: text-list data (map-each section jobs_data/sections [section/title]) [
        currently_selected: pick jobs_data/sections face/cnt
        jobs/data: (map-each job currently_selected/jobs [job/title]) show jobs
    ]

    jobs: text-list
]
```

I'm not certain that `face/cnt` is the best way to get the index of the selected list item.  Anyone?

Comment: You can use GET-FACE to get a block of selected items.

Comment: That appears to give the text of the selected item in the text-list as a block but not necessarily the position that face/cnt gives.